# Place an image partially above toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-relativelayout

I would like how can do to have an image in my relative layout to be above (on top layer) my toolbar (in the same relative layout) and not below it. Any idea ?
The layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/splash"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/my_toolbar"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


    <include
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/my_toolbar"
        ></include>

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

the toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                               android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                               android:background="#7dca2c"
                               android:elevation="4dp"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Can you post the content of your Toolbar layout

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the `RelativeLayout`, your `FrameLayout` will handle that just fine.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/my_toolbar"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/splash"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontally"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

By having the included layout as the first child, it will be the first layer - and the `ImageView` will be the second. Adding `android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontally"` to the `ImageView` will then align it correctly within the `ViewGroup`.

Comment: I have just tried, it doesn't work :(, the image is still under my toolbar.

Comment: It should work, please show me exactly what you tried and the result you received.